# Edit the admin panel using Custom user authentication

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-authentication

Using the documentation I am trying to create a custom authentication model in order to be able to use only Email and password to authenticate a user.

Despite I manage to do it, I am having trouble to edit the Admin panel and in particular the Edit form could you please help me to add the possible editable field.
my code is :

```
admin.py:
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField

from registration.models import MyUser


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('email','is_active','is_hr','is_candidate','is_employee','company','first_name','last_name')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_admin','is_hr','is_candidate','is_employee','company','first_name','last_name')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'is_admin','is_active', 'is_admin','is_hr','is_candidate','is_employee','company','first_name','last_name')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()

# Now register the new UserAdmin...
admin.site.register(MyUser, UserAdmin)
# ... and, since we're not using Django's built-in permissions,
# unregister the Group model from admin.
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

model.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)


class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_Euser(self, email):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email,
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
        )

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    first_name= models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    last_name= models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_hr = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_candidate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add all you model fields.for that you should have to add field in `fieldsets` under `UserAdmin`.

change you `fieldsets` as below:

```
fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password','company','first_name','last_name')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin','is_active','is_hr','is_candidate','is_employee')}),
    )
```

Above changes will add fields to django-admin.